# What does "default collection in your Angular CLI project" mean?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngrx

I installed "@ngrx/schematics" and it asked me -

> "Do you want to use @ngrx/schematics as the default collection?"

I am not sure what "default collection" means.

The default value is "Yes". Selecting "Yes" adds this entry to the angular.json file:

```
"cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics"
  }
```

I could not find any documentation as to what being a "default collection" exactly means. The [ngrx page](https://ngrx.io/guide/schematics/install) only mentions the flag as optional -

> defaultCollection - Use @ngrx/schematics as the default collection.

and [this angular page](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config) mentions

> The default schematics collection to use.

Follow up question - If I want to remove this change, then what should I do ? Should I just removethe entry from angular.json or replace it with some other value ?

Comment: You can change it to @nrwl/angular (for example) which makes most cli commands you use less verbose. For example, to create a lib: nx g @nrwl/angular:lib mylib - but if you use @nrwl/angular as default you’d use nx g lib mylib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is for the `ng cli` tool (`ng g`) to extend from the base schematics automatically without prepending the package schematics name:

If you specify anything different, like
@angular-eslint/schematics, @ngrx/schematics. It enables command like ng generate to execute package specific command and settings automatically, like `ng generate create-effect-migration` instead of `ng generate @ngrx/schematics:create-effect-migration`

It has been replaced by `schematicCollection` as of writing(a list of default schematics to extend).